# Locking Data Structures in Distributed Systems

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, distributed

I am entirely new to the concepts of distributed systems. Kindly let me know even if the question should be rephrased.

I am trying to make a distributed systems with 10 clients and one server. There is a queue at server side, that can be accessed by clients one at a time. So what kind of locking mechanism could be used so as to avoid spurious data? Are semaphores feasible in this situation? If possible, kindly provide a reference, so as to have a much deeper knowledge of the same.

Comment: This is a big topic. I suggest you search for some introductions to the subject and get a sense of what the main issues are. It's not reasonable to expect someone to write a dissertation on distributed systems on a stack overflow post to answer all your questions.

Comment: @Steve B. - Okay, I will look into it and be specific next time.

Answer (score 1):

Semaphores on the server are feasible, and indeed are the way to go.  On a GNU/Linux system such as Debian, see `man 7 sem_overview` and `man 1 lockfile`.

The simplest method is probably to let the server serve no more than one client at a time, refusing all requests from other clients.  A refused client waits a random (not definite) length of time, then tries again.

Another method can be to let the server queue requests, but this is more complicated (and may still involve refusing some requests).